# div is full width but the listbox inside would not expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want my listboc to expand the whole width of screen, in this image

[image]

So the highlighted list box under text "select or double-click...." is the one which is not expanding the whole width of screen.

Markup

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top:10px;" id="divCommentBank">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px;">
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="width:200px; border:groove; margin-left: 20px">
                <label style="width:100%">Comment Categories</label>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.cM.CategoryList, new SelectList(Model.cM.CategoryList, "CategoryID", "Description"), new { @id = "listCommentCategory", @style = "height:168px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 5px; width:190px" })

            </div>
            <div style="float: right; width:900px; border:groove; margin-right: 20px">
                <div class="row" style="margin-top:5px; padding-top:0px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-4" style=" margin-left: 5px">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.cM.HeaderList, new SelectList(Model.cM.HeaderList, "CommentID", "Comment"), new { @id = "ddlCommentHeaders", @style="width: 100%" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        Search:
                        @Html.TextBox("txtSearchHeader")
                        <button id="clear">X</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                        <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" >
                    <div style="margin-left:5px" class=" col-xs-9">
                        Select or double-click on a comment to insert:
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top:5px">
                    <div style="margin-left:5px; " class=" col-xs-9">
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.cM.CommentsList, new SelectList(Model.cM.CommentsList, "CommentID", "Comment"), new { @id = "listComments", @style = "height:105px; margin-bottom:5px;" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

After adding display:inline OR display:inline-block to each of the 3 rows and setting width: 100% now the image is[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show us a demo link , or codepen

Comment: What is the actual HTML produced by `@Html.ListBoxFor()`? What are the `row` and `col-xs-9` classes? Is there any other CSS that might apply to that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding the below attribute to the parent div of listbox?

display: inline or display: inline-block

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:5px;display:inline;">
                <div style="margin-left:5px; " class=" col-xs-9">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.cM.CommentsList, new SelectList(Model.cM.CommentsList, "CommentID", "Comment"), new { @id = "listComments", @style = "height:105px; margin-bottom:5px;" })
                </div>
```

OR

```
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:5px;display:inline-block;">
                <div style="margin-left:5px; " class=" col-xs-9">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.cM.CommentsList, new SelectList(Model.cM.CommentsList, "CommentID", "Comment"), new { @id = "listComments", @style = "height:105px; margin-bottom:5px;" })
                </div>
```

Comment: i have added style=" display: inline" to each of the 3 rows and set width:100%..but the width is same..although there is some change in margins of each row

Comment: max-width: 100%. This might help, am thinking that some parent element is overwriting your css. Could you run developer's tool and dom explorer to find exact css on that listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `display: inline-block` attribute to each `.row`

Answer (score 0):

The select element is generally an inline-block element by default.
Have you tried setting `width: 100%;` in the ListBox styles?

Comment: Don't select elements normally default to the width required to display the longest option text?